# LWJGL 2 Camera Movement According to mouse

Tags: camera, mouse, lwjgl

Hello I'm new to OpenGl and lwjgl. I have been developing a game for some times and I have reached a problem. I use the mouse.getdx and dy to rotate around but obviasly when i press the wasd (default movemnt keys) they wont change according to the direction. I have tried some examples but none of them worked. Here's the code:
https://pastebin.com/UXHGGh5n`Code`
Any ideas of how to solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply store the desired changes in a Vector, then multiply this with the inverse of you camera matrix and add the result to your position.
 For example, your method `move` could look like this:

```
public void move() {
    Vector3f movement = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
    float x = Mouse.getX();

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W))
        movement.z-=0.02f;
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D))
        movement.x+=0.02f;
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))
        movement.x-=0.02f;
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S))
        movement.z+=0.02f; 

    movement = yourCameraMatrix.inverse().multiply(movement);
    position.add(movement);
}
```

I'm not sure if lwjgl has its own methods for multiplying matrices and vectors, so you might have to program these youself. Besides that this should work though.

Comment: I am going to try that when i get home and ill let you know thanks in advance =D

Comment: Hey how would i do this movement = MainGameHandler.shader.viewMatrix.invert().multiply(movement); Lwjgl has a method for the invert but none for the multiply of vectors per matrixes ive searched an found nothing. thanks in advance

Comment: As I said, you might have to program some of these methods yourself, depending on your lwjgl version. This shouldn't be too hard to do however; see https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136573/multiply-matrix4x4-with-vec4 for some ways of doing this.

Comment: I think i got it to add but i cant get it to inverse this is what i have so far System.out.println(viewMatrix);
     System.out.println(movement);
     
     movement = Matrix4f.transform(viewMatrix,movement,movement);
     
     position = Vector3f.add(position,new Vector3f(movement.x,movement.y,movement.z),position);

Comment: I think this should work: `Matrix4f invertedViewMatrix = new Matrix4f(); Matrix4f.invert(viewMatrix,invertedViewMatrix); Matrix4f.transform(invertedViewMatrix,movement,movement); position.x=movement.x;position.y+=movement.y;position.z+=movement.z;`

Comment: Thanks it worked jsut perfectly =D Just had to change the Movement from Vector3f to Vector4f and leave the last one as 0

Comment: also changed position.x=movement.x; to position.x+=movement.x; so it works on the x axis =D